# Error when running famous dev on famo.us

Tags: node.js, famo.us, famous-cli

I am installing famo.us, and I created a project, then went into the folder and ran `famous dev` like it says here, but then I get an error:

http://famous.org/get-started.html

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>famous create messenger
Seed project created at: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger\messenger

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>cd messenger

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger\messenger>famous dev
Node Modules not yet installed, attempting to do so now.
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger\messenger>
```

Comment: It is true [there is an issue with the famous-cli on windows](https://github.com/Famous/famous-cli/issues/11) at the time of your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in windows. 
First run ***npm install*** from the command prompt.
Then, in package.json change the "dev" line under "scripts" to:
    ***"dev": "npm run watch | serve public/ -p 1618",***

and then run ***npm run dev*** from the command line (instead of ***famous dev***)

Comment: Using the pipe is not recommended. Windows does not handle parallel commands in a shell. It would be better to run the two commands in separate shells.

Answer (score 0):

The error when running `famous dev` has been resolved as of [Famous-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/famous-cli) version [0.2.8](https://github.com/Famous/famous-cli/releases/tag/v0.2.8)

#### Run this command at the command line with npm enabled

```
npm update -g famous-cli
```

**Note:** There is an issue with parallel commands in windows using npm so you will not get a watched server when running `famous dev` from the default `famous create` seed as of version 0.2.8